# select the label of an input that is focused

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<nav>
    <label class="my-label" for="my-field">hello</label>
</nav>

<form class="my-form" action="" method="GET">
    <input class="my-input" type="text" name="search-field">
</form>
```

I need a css selector that selects the label.my-label when the input.my-input is focused.

Something like `.my-label if .my-input:focused { color: red; }`.

This should change the text color of the label to red if the input is focused.

Is there something that can do this in the current browsers?

Comment: There are no ancestor selectors in CSS. You'll need scripting.

Comment: Yes, with JavaScript. Or place your label next to the input (which has an existing CSS solution). Why is yours `<label>` outside `<form>`? that is just dirty.

Comment: _“Is there something that can do this in the current browsers?”_ - not with that HTML structure. The input field would have to come first, and whatever you want to format based on it having focus, would need to be a sibling of, or inside a sibling of the input field.

Comment: @KarelG my label is in the navigation because it acts as a "search button" which on click focuses the search field input. when the input filed is focused, the :focus of the input field selector makes it visible

Comment: you can Achieve it using jquery, Check this: https://codepen.io/kareemda/pen/wVyNQY

Comment: If you place the `label` immediately after the `input` element, you may use `plus(+)`, (`.my-input:focus+.my-label-1 {
            color: red
}`)otherwise, you have to achieve this through the script.

Comment: and then if the label should be displayed above the input on the screen,  you can achieve that by using `display:flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;` on the form.

Comment: I don't think you can without changing your HTML,You should move Label tag to bottom of Input tag then use this css: .my-input:focus + .my-label{
 color:red;
}